# c# Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count not returning expected when using MaxDegreeOfParallelism?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm doing something like this..

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{ 
    Parallel.ForEach(list, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (listitem, state) =>
    {
        //do stuff here
        Console.writeln(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);               
    });
});
```

The number of threads is my application is always in excess of 10? What am I doing wrong to limit the number of threads my app uses?

Comment: Why do you care how many threads it uses? What you should be concerned about is the number of threads that are actually doing work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx):

> By default, For and ForEach will utilize however many threads the underlying scheduler provides, so changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from the default only limits how many concurrent tasks will be used.

Thus, the *thread count* will exceed 10, however no more than 10 of those threads will run at a single time. This saves the underlying framework the hassle of having to track each thread and append code to it, possibly destabilizing one operation if another faults. Instead, we find it making arbitrarily many threads and throttling how many can run at a time.

You can even test this by adding a Count to the class, and seeing how high it ever goes:

```
// In the class scope
int _count = 0;
int MaxCount = 0;
object key = new object();

int Count
{
    get { lock(key) return _count; }
    set
    {
        lock(key)
        {
            _count = value;
            if(_count > MaxCount) MaxCount = value;
        }
    }
}
...
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{ 
    Parallel.ForEach(list, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (listitem, state) =>
    {
        Count++;
        Console.writeln(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
        Count--;            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`MaxDegreeOfParallelism` doesn't limit the number of threads of your process (your console app for example). It limits the number of threads for the operation you are trying to run in parallel within `Parallel.ForEach`

Your application in the meantime might run x number of additional threads in parallel and `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count` counts them all.